Generate drf-spectacular schema for a fixed string response
In my DRF application, few of get() and post() methods always return a fixed message response like below:
def post()

  // other code

  return Response({ "message": "Your request has been accepted" })

Is there a way to capture this in schema as is instead of { "message": "string" }?
I have tried @extend_schema like below, but the responses schema has only "string" (attached image)
@extend_schema(responses={200:{"message": "Your request has been accepted" }})
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  return Response({ "message": "Your request has been accepted" })


Update:
Below decorate seems to work fine and similar to what I am expecting.
@extend_schema(
   responses = {
      200: OpenApiResponse(
         response = inline_serializer(
            name = "change-request",
            fields = { "message": serializers.CharField(default="Your request has been accepted") }
         )
      )
   },
)


But I have many APIs that return plain text message, so adding this decorator to all those methods doesn't feel right.
Please let me know if there is a better way for this.

probably you need this:
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema

@extend_schema(responses={200:{"message": "Your request has been accepted" }})
def get()
  return Response({ "message": "Your request has been accepted" })

more here:
https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-2-extend-schema

I had tried this, in responses schema it just says "string", updating the question with the details.
